# How to reset a root password using the passphrase ?

Tags: debian, passwords, root, passphrase

I've lost my root password and I would like to recover it (as you might have guessed).

I have the passphrase but don't know what I can do with it ?

Thanks

Comment: The passphrase supposedly is to unencrypt? Not related to the root password of the OS.

Comment: As @MichaelBay asked - are you asked for a passphrase on bootup - and if so, is it used to decrypt a partition ?   (If its not required to decrypt the partition /etc is mounted on - which is usually the root partition - you can reset the password without a passphrase)